# Storybook conversion to CSF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

In the process of converting React Stories to use the advised [CSF](https://storybook.js.org/docs/formats/component-story-format/)

I'm wondering how can the following (stories that are generated from looping an array of objects) be converted to CSF?

ps: my real array has over 15 items. this is just an example below

```js
const stories = storiesOf("MyStories", module)

const storyOptions = [{name: "foo", age:21}, {name: "bar", age: 22},{name: "batman", age: 23}, ] // 

for (let option of storyOptions) {
  stories.add(option.name, () => {
    return <MyWrapperComponent option={option} />
  })
}
```

I'm having difficulties refactoring the above to output the same multiple stories as CSF:
Only the first story returns so far:

```js
export const myStories = () => {
  for (let option of storyOptions) {
    return <MyWrapperComponent option={option} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Storybook 5.x, the latest version available as I'm writing this, it's not possible to iterate over an array and dynamically generate stories with CSF format because the requirements to have working stories are strict:
 - a required default export
 - one or more named exports

Everything is fine with the default export however there is currently no way to have dynamic named exports because JS `import`and `export` have to be statically analyzable - i.e. known before executing the code. Unfortunately, you are stuck with the old syntax for now.

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9805